# Driver object data property will generate a "Could not find op_from" warning

Tags: animation, drivers

I set a custom property on the object data and referred to it from the driver, but I don't understand the following two points.

1. The following warning is displayed on the system console

```
add_relation(RNA Target -> Driver) - Could not find op_from (RnaPathKey(id: OBCube.001, prop: 'prop'))
add_relation(RNA Target -> Driver) - Failed, but op_to (OperationKey(type: PARAMETERS, component name: '', operation code: DRIVER, 'location')) was ok
```

The message 'prop' not found for Cube object looks strange.

2. Update Dependancies must be pressed for this to be reflected.

If I press Update Dependancies, it is reflected in the driver normally, but in light of the above two points, is there something wrong with the usage?
[image]

blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fFVmDdvHtvrf1iGGOcnUSqzH8DUorpc8/view?usp=sharing

-------------------------------------------------

Comment: You appear to have shared an empty blend file.  Can you make sure you're sharing one that has the objects and drivers?

Comment: you got the property set on the mesh, so in the var definition don't pick the object as ID, directly pick the mesh data, it would be Cube.001 and use ["Prop"] as the path

Comment: @alambre 
Thanks I have confirmed that there is no problem with the mesh data. But is data["prop"] an incorrect setting? The question remains.

Because I do not see any error on the screen and the values are reflected normally by update dependencies.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks for trying to confirm. This is a file saved with 3.0, so I can't seem to open it with 2.9 or earlier.

Comment: @Carboro Aha.  I can open it with 3.01, so I'll take a look at it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the custom property is actually associated with the *Mesh* but your driver is trying to use it as if it were associate with the *Object* that the mesh is in.

To solve it, I deleted the driver, selected `Cube.001`, hovered over the data field for `prop`, right clicked and selected *Copy as new driver*.  Next I selected `Cube`, hovered over the Z transform input in the side panel, right clicked and selected *paste driver*.  Finally, I clicked "Update dependencies".

That done, Your driver looks like:

[image: Driver editor window]

Notice that the editor decided to call the variable `prop`, since that's the name of the custom property, and that instead of the type field being *Object* it is *Mesh*.

Notice also that Path that the driver editor picked: `["prop"]`.

I don't know why the error messages you received were so weird but that's the problem and at least one solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!
I understand that the mesh property solves the problem. However, I still have a question as to why the original settings do not work. Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: @carboro Blender can be a bit confusing about the relationship between objects and meshes.  You added the property to the mesh (as seen in the properties window) but tried to use a property that was attached to the object.(as seen in the driver window) I think you're right that there's a bug.  Blender tried to make the connection between the object path RNA you gave it in the drive and the actual property's RNA in the mesh and botched it; producing an incomprehensible error message.  It should have just told you "no such Path" instead.